# Pandas DataFrame step plot: where="post"

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am wondering how I can pass matplotlibs [where="post"](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/step_demo.html) into a pandas plot.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(36, 3))
df.plot(drawstyle="steps", linewidth=2)

# this doesn't work
df.plot(drawstyle="steps", where='post')
```

Does anyone know how to realize this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You just need to specify `drawstyle="steps-post"`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(36, 3))
df.plot(drawstyle="steps", linewidth=2)
df.plot(drawstyle="steps-post", linewidth=2)
```

Compare the result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!! Btw: is this documented somewhere? Couldn't find it in the pandas documentation..

Comment: Well, I admit I guess my way all along..., but these keys words eventually all get passed to `line` object, and the document does mention it: http://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party but: is there a way to add a horizontal line for the first (final) point in the top (bottom) graph? I.e., when these are time intervals, and the quantity displayed is constant in each interval.

Comment: In response to the question posed by @ElRudi -- not that I'm aware of (when configuring the plot). What I typically do in such circumstances is create a copy of the data being plotted and add leading/trailing observations as needed to emulate the effect (leaving the original data unchanged.)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a matplotlib plot? [Click here for an example.](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/step_demo.html)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.step(range(len(df.index)),df[0],where='post')
plt.step(range(len(df.index)),df[1],where='post')
plt.step(range(len(df.index)),df[2],where='post')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I prefer pandas plots for basic plotting since it requires less code.