# How plot a curve and and timeline bar graph in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm looking to plot a graph representing multiple data according to the steps of an SFC process. To illustrate in a simple way, here is a drawing where I took a data in the shape of a staircase and I would also like to add the areas of the SFC, represented here in colors but I do not know at all what style of graph this is.

otherwise it can be a single color but with delimitations and step labels.

Automatically just read the data df.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The step diagram, you can do under `pandas` by using the "steps" drawstyle, as described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35067304/pandas-dataframe-step-plot-where-post). Here's a code example:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2,  1, 1]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.plot(drawstyle='steps')
```

This example returns:

[image]

The separation you can easily achieve by drawing vertical lines with `matplotlib`'s `axvline` built-in function. If you want a background with a specific color as in your example plot, then go for the `axvspan` function.

Here is an example code to tackle this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.axvspan(xmin=0, xmax=3, color='cornflowerblue')
plt.axvspan(xmin=3, xmax=5, color='orange')
plt.axvspan(xmin=5, xmax=10, color='yellow')
```

This code will return:

[image]

Comment: Misunderstant, my problem is the area not the step curve. But the axvspan is a solution ! thanks